# Is there a high limit on how high the Tenser's Floating Disk will fly?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, 3d-space, spells

Is there a high limit on how high the disk will fly? If i'm on it and use a move action to go "UP" how far will it go before it refuses to go any farther? I did not see any mention of high limits other than within 5 squares of you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The disc always floats 1 foot off the ground.**

The rules say:

> You create a slightly concave, circular plane of force that **floats a foot off the ground** and can carry what you lay upon it. The disk is 3 feet in diameter and 1 inch deep at its center. It remains stationary unless you move more than 5 squares away from it, in which case it moves with your base speed once per round until it is within 5 squares of you. You can command the disk to move up to your speed as a move action. If you are more than 5 squares from the disk for 2 consecutive rounds, the disk disappears, dropping whatever it was carrying. <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=60) (emphasis added)</sup>

- If you fly up, you will eventually move more than 5 squares away from it.
- At that point, it will move as close as it can to you.
- But since it remains only one foot off the ground, it will just hover directly below you.
- If you remain in the air more than 5 squares away from it for 2 consecutive rounds, the disk goes away. *Poof.*

**The rules do not say what happens if you summon a disc while already flying.**

There are multiple interpretations of the first sentence quoted above.

1. The disc is **created below you** at a point one foot off the ground.
2. The disc is **created nearby but immediately falls** until it is one foot off the ground.
3. The disc **cannot be created** because it must always float a foot off the ground.

Frankly, I'd go with #3.

Comment: So if you were already flying, and summon the disk, it would fall until it was one foot off the ground, or would it hover next to you? Also what counts as ground, if you have a 5x5 piece of stone under the disk, and that is moved up, say 10 feet, would the disk phase through that stone, or hover 1 foot above it?

Comment: @Kedearian - Tenser's Floating Disk is a ritual that takes 10 minutes to cast.  Assuming you can fly for those 10 minutes you still need to "perform various actions appropriate to the ritual"  Personally I would rule that you would have to cast it so that it came into being 1 foot off the ground.  Ground that you have just spend 10 minutes drawing a nice power invoking rune of some sort on.

Comment: @Pat - If you have flight naturally or something else that is keeping you aloft, for 10 minuets in the same spot, what would stop you from doing the ritual in flight? There is no description that the ritual requires any circle or runes. It could be just chanting or focus for 10 minuets

Comment: @Kedearian - It could be.  And I'd have no problem with your DM ruling it so.  The text I quoted earlier is from the standard definition of how to perform a ritual.  The specifics of each one are not given anywhere that I know of.  This gives the DM considerable leeway for interpretation.  I just told you how I would rule.  I see no reason to allow the disk to come into being in an illegal spot.  If this was my campaign, I'd encourage you to design a similar but different (higher level) ritual to accomplish what you seem to want to do.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a discussion of summoning a disc while in the air.

Comment: @Adam - Thanks!   I was debating the logic of creating my own answer to cover it.  This is much better.